# Swift - Dates from server keep getting converted into my local timezone

Tags: swift

I am parsing JSON data from a server, which I can set to 'UK' or 'Asia'

Function:

```
func dateToStringConverter(jsonDate: String) -> String {
let isoDate = jsonDate
let dateFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
let processedDate = dateFormatter.date(from:isoDate)!

return processedDate.asString()}
```

Extension:

```
extension Date {


func asString() -> String {

let template = "EEEEd MMMM, h:mm a"
let formatter = DateFormatter()
let format = DateFormatter.dateFormat(fromTemplate: template, options: 0, locale: NSLocale.current)
formatter.dateFormat = format

return formatter.string(from: self)}}


print(dateToStringConverter(jsonDate: jsonDate))
```

Then, the following attribute from the server differs based on if I set 'UK or 'Asia':

```
let jsonDate = "2020-10-05T02:15:00+08:00" // server set to Asia

let jsonDate = "2020-10-04T19:15:00+01:00" // server set to UK
```

However, BOTH these values result in the SAME OUTPUT from the print statement!

```
Sunday, October 4, 7:15 PM
```

I believe what is happening here is, even if I set the server to Asia, Swift knows I am in the UK, and therefore prints Sunday, October 4, 7:15 PM

Is this correct?

If so, is there any way to mimic what print statement from Asia would see? I have tried changing the region in the simulator, but this didn't seem to make a difference

Thanks

Comment: It is correct, `2020-10-05T02:15:00+08:00` and `2020-10-04T19:15:00+01:00` is the same point in time but in different time zones.

Comment: If you want the DateFormatter to create strings for another time zone, set the formatter's `timeZone` property. If you want to change your simulator's time zone (so that the "current" time zone changes), I believe you'll need to change the current time zone for your Mac. I don't believe the simulator has its own clock.

Comment: Nothing is being "converted". A date is a date is a date. The _printed output_ is a completely different matter; there are different ways of _saying_ what the date is. But it's the same date.

Answer (score 0):

The good thing about zoned ISO 8601 timestamps is that they represent a specific moment in UTC time. They do not contain information about which time zone they're from, as this is highly ambiguous. If you aim for easier human comparability, understandability and a reduction in ambiguity, I suggest going for UTC time.

In stead of

2020-01-01T02:00:00+01:00

you'd have

2020-01-01T01:00:00Z

Z is a shortcut for +00:00

When it ends in Z, it's always UTC time and thus easily comparable.